# Can't get NSTableView to display data

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nstableview

I see there are a lot of questions about this, but nothing helped me to get this work.
I have a nib with a NSTableView with three columns (with the right identifiers set) and a class named ShortcutsTableController. In the nib I have a NSObject with class value ShortcutsTableController. I also connected the NSTableView to my controller as I usually do.

This is header `ShortcutsTableController.h`.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface ShortcutsTableController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet NSTableView *shortcutsTable;
    NSMutableArray *shortcutsList;
}

- (int) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView*) tableView;
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *shortcutsTable;
- (void)setUpTable;

@end
```

And this is the implementation file `ShortcutsTableController.m`.

```
#import "ShortcutsTableController.h"

@implementation ShortcutsTableController

@synthesize shortcutsTable;

- (void)setUpTable {

    shortcutsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"blabla", @"nameColumn", 
                           @"Bla bla bla", @"shortcutColumn",
                           @"Ribla", @"actionColumn", nil];

    [shortcutsList addObject:dict1];

    [shortcutsTable setDataSource:self];
    [shortcutsTable reloadData];
}

-(int) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView *) tableView {
    return [shortcutsList count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row {

    if (row != -1)
        return [[shortcutsList objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:[tableColumn identifier]];

    return nil;
}

@end
```

But when i try to build nothing appears in the NSTableView. No errors, no warnings. Note that I call setUpTable from within the Delegate Class Method `awakeFromNib`.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Thank you for you help.

—Albé

UPDATE. Added lines `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *shortcutsTable;` in header and `@synthesize shortcutsTable;` in implementation. Nothing changes. :(

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", shortcutsTable);` produce in `setUpTable`?

Comment: (null). :O Can't understand this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the results of your `NSLog` statement in `setUpTable:`, you don't have your IBOutlet set up.  Perhaps you did, but it somehow got lost (undo, overwrite, accidentally deleted it, etc).  You'll need to go back to Interface Builder and re-establish the connection between `ShortcutsTableController` and the `NSTableView` in the xib.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It's very strange, I went back to Interface Builder and tried to re-establish the connection (which was already there). I tried also to remove the TableView and to re-add it, but it's always (null). IB says the controller and the NSTableView are connected, but in fact they aren't. :(

Comment: Ok... The connection is now active (I don't know why :O). The value is not (null), but nothing appears in the table. If I add the elements and reload during init all goes as expected, but if I add items to the array after init, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

How many objects in shortcutsList?

Try to iterate through the dictionary anywhere else but the datasource methods to see if its displaying data correctly.

Also, have you set the controller as the datasource of that table in IB or manually in your awakeFromNib?

Comment: Manually in `setUpTable`: `[shortcutsTable setDataSource:self];`, but I connected also in Nib (CTRL drag from NSTableView to the controller, than I selected dataSource).

Comment: I tried also to add a NSLog() to the tableView method, but in the console nothing appears. It seems that it is never used, even when i call reloadData.

Comment: Is the controller the delegate for the table?

Comment: Yes. The table is updated only when I reload from the init method of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling [table reloadData] when you update shortcutList?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

to your code where 1 is the number of sections you have in your table